# Bash [[ pattern matching not working

Tags: bash, quoting, test

The [Bash reference section on conditional constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) says:

```
When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the 
operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described 
below in Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled. ...
An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same precedence as 
‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is 
considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex 
3)).
```

But then I try this:

```
$ [[ -good == -* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -g == -* ]] ; echo $?
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-*'
$ [[ -g == -? ]] ; echo $?
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-?'
```

Then I try the regex matching operator `=~`:

```
$ [[ -good =~ -.* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -g =~ -.* ]] ; echo $?
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-.*'
$ [[ -g =~ -.? ]] ; echo $?
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-.?'
```

Why the syntax errors?

Answer (score 4):

Well you have to be careful that the text to the left of `==`, `=~` or `!=` is not one of the [operators recognized in Bash conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

In your case, `-g` tests for a `setgid` bit set. If you had provided something that is not recognized as an operator in this context, then it would work:

```
$ [[ -i == -* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -i == -? ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -i =~ -.* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ -i =~ -.? ]] ; echo $?
0
```

One way to reliably provide any string would be to quote it, so it is recognized not as an operator but as just a string:

```
$ [[ "-good" == -* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "-g" == -* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "-g" == -? ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "-good" =~ -.* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "-g" =~ -.* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ "-g" =~ -.? ]] ; echo $?
0
```

However take care not to quote the *right hand side* of the operator since it will prevent that from being recognized as a pattern:

```
$ [[ "-good" == "-*" ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ "-g" == "-*" ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ "-g" == "-?" ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ "-good" =~ "-.*" ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ "-g" =~ "-.*" ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ "-g" =~ "-.?" ]] ; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

We should put the string inside quotes to evaluate them as strings. If we try to evaluate a string having embedded hyphen(-) then shell will consider it as an option to test but not as string. For more information on the operators you can check this [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Control_structures/comparison_operators.shtml)